# C unsigned int x = 1; smaller than int y = -1;

Tags: c

i do know the differences of signed unsigened etc.
But i don´t understand the following code:

```
unsigned int x = 1;
int y = -1;
    if(y < x)
        printf("of course it is");
    else
        printf("strange stuff");
```

1 should be a greater number than -1, no matter which representation is used. Because "strange stuff" will be displayed on the console.

Comment: The operator (<) cannot compare signed to unsigned, so it converts one of them to the other type. In this case, it converts y to unsigned (which makes it a large number).

Comment: **ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C)**

[§6.5.8 Relational operators](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.8.html)

-1202 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed.

Both operands will be casted to be `unsigned int`, and in Two's Complement, 
`unsigned int y = -1; // = 4294967296 = 2^32 since integers are 32-bit.`
Thus you're comparing `4294967296 < 1` which is false.

Comment: Well that explains the outcome. But why will be y converted to an unsigned int. To match the types, x could be converted to Two´s Complement.

Answer (score 2):

signed 1 (as byte) in bits: 00000001

unsigned 1 in bits: 00000001

signed -1 in bits: 10000001 (or 1 1111111, just details)

unsigned -1 in bits: no valid representation (10000001  is 129)

if you want safely compare signed and unsigned variables, than you have two ways:

1) take in account signs and manually compare them (<s>e. g. `isSignedLess = (signed < 0) || ((unsigned <= max_signed) && (signed < unsigned))`</s> )

2) cast both to bigger singed (i. e. signed long long) and than compare them (signed long long can store all diapason of signed/unsigned int's)

---

As you can see in comments, both ways are kinda tricky. Just don't mix  signed and unsigned wherever you can. It's possible in 99% cases. In last 1% cases you really need to know what you doing (e. g. often had to use signed indexes with vectors, but size() - unsigned, so I ask myself hundred time "can this vector reach MAX_INT or not? have I to do more complex code or it's ok for this task?").

Comment: `isSignedLess = (signed < 0) || ((unsigned <= max_signed) && (signed < unsigned))` is the right idea, yet can be simplified.  `isSignedLess = (signed_a < 0) || (signed_a < unsigned_b);`.  The cast to bigger `signed is not always possible as a wider signed type may not exist.

Comment: First of all, as already was said, it's not recommended mixing signed and unsigned. I'm just wrote a bit hacky workaround. Secondary, `signed_a < unsigned_b` can cause same problem, if compiler decide to trunc unsigned to signed (yeah, "standard saying...."... I don't like to remember tiny details, if there is straightforward and obviously code)

Comment: "if compiler decide to trunc unsigned to signed" does not happen in C.

Comment: The is UV-ed because it does not caution against "mixing signed and unsigned".  Instead it address OP's issue of how to handle mixed sign-ness compares with #1.

Comment: On 2nd look `isSignedLess = (signed < 0) || ((unsigned <= max_signed) && (signed < unsigned)))` is wrong.  `(unsigned <= max_signed)` incorrectly causes false compare with `unsigned int x = UINT_MAX; int y = 0;` to fail.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake.

Comment: It is possible (however unlikely) for `long` and `long long` types to be the same size, making "`signed long long` can store all diapason of `signed`/`unsigned` `int`s" not strictly true.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an unsigned int with a signed int. You shouldn't do that. C fixes this by converting one of them to the type of the other. In this case it probably converts y to an unsigned int making it positive so x should be the same as y.

You sould make them both an int, or if it's really necessary you can cast the unsigned int to an int when comparing.

`if(y<(int)x)`

Comment: In fact, according to the C standard, the conversion is always done to the signed type, making it unsigned.

Comment: `if(y<(int)x)` moves the problem to other pairs such as  `unsigned int x = INT_MAX + 2u; int y = 0;`